# Make button unclickable until certain conditions are met in TitleAreaDialog?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am making a login dialog for a eclipse plugin and I was wondering what would be the best way to check if certain condition are met before you can submit the dialog. 
Currently I am overriding the okPressed() function and then not running the super function until the conditions are met.

This is unfortunately not ideal because the user has no indication of what is wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean submit the dialog? did u mean click on submit button in yOur dialog?your question is too vague :)

Comment: Yup I meant when I click the Ok button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable the OK button using something like:

```
Button ok = getButton(IDialogConstants.OK_ID);
if (ok != null)
  ok.setEnabled(false);
```

You can set a message at the top of the dialog using

```
setMessage("message", type);
```

`type` can be `IMessageProvider.ERROR`, `IMessageProvider.WARNING`, `IMessageProvider.INFORMATION` or `IMessageProvider.NONE`.

So you can add listeners to your input fields and each time a field changes update the message and OK button enable state as required.

Comment: how would I enable the button automatically once a valid input is typed in? (eg both the username and password is not blank)

Comment: Added info on listeners.

Answer (score 0):

To show the error/warning to your user, you can use the `TitleAreaDialog.setMessage()` with the message and type of message.